# Can I package and utilize a dll with an MFC ActiveX Control Object?

Tags: dll, activex, cab

I've been able to create a signed CAB file for web deployment containing my control and dll, but my control seems unable to access classes and functions in my dll even though it is listed as a dependency in the CAB's inf file.  For all my research, I can't even tell if what I'm trying to do is "allowed". Followup: if it is possible to talk to a non-com dll, is it a security risk?

I'm using msvc 2010.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty certain what I was trying to do wasn't possible.  Ended up creating a class library instead so that I could reference and include the functions I needed at compile time.